# Unequal results after array merge

Tags: java, arrays, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm trying to concatenate many byte[] arrays into one, big array. I've found a solution utilizing ByteArrayOutputStream but I find results weird.

Code

```
List<SampleChunk> chunkList = new ArrayList<SampleChunk>();

public static byte[] getRaw(List<SampleChunk> list) throws FileNotFoundException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        try {
            os.write(list.get(i).getSamples());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(new File("all.txt"));
    pr.write(Arrays.toString(os.toByteArray()));
    pr.close();

    return os.toByteArray();
}
public void init(){
   XuggleAudio xa = new XuggleAudio(new File("in.flv"));

    PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(new File("chunks.txt"));
    int count = 0;

    SampleChunk sc = null;
    while ((sc = xa.nextSampleChunk()) != null) {
        pr.write(count++ + " " + Arrays.toString(sc.getSamples()) + "\n");
        chunkList.add(sc);
    }

    getRaw(chunkList);
}
```

Problem is, that theese two output doesn't match. PrintWriter in init() method prints something like this

```
0 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
2 [45, -1, -78, -4, 48, -1, -63, -4, 86,
3 [-38, -1, -55, -1, -62, -1, 85
4 ...
```

but output form getRaw() method contains only values from {-1,1,0,2}. Both output have the same size (os.toByteArray().length == list.size * (...)getSamples.lenght). What did I wrong? How to merge theese arrays right?

Comment: In the first case, you are processing the sample chucks immediately.  In the second, you are storing the chunk buffers and processing them all after all reading has been done.  What if, internal to `XuggleAudio` buffers are reused?  The 50th buffer object might reuse the first buffer object's internal storage, 'cause that was an entire second ago, no point keeping the data around or allocating more memory.  Does `getRaw()` output look like the end of the `init()` output?

Comment: OK. I changed chunkList to List<byte[]> and it works. Thank you very much